# Ruby - "undefined method" in alphabetical sorting program

Tags: ruby, methods

I've tried to create a program that will take in strings, then sort them alphabetically, but I've hit a bump that I can't seem to understand with my current level.
If I run the code without the if branch, then things are fine; but the moment I do this:

> junk.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined method`ord' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)

If I remove the `ord` method, I get the same message with `split` in place of "ord" in the returned message.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

CODE:

```
words = []
cWords = nil
x = 0
y = 0

while (cWords != "")
  cWords = gets.chomp
  words[x] = cWords
  x = x + 1
end

x = 0

while (y < 200) #arbitrary limit at the moment
  if (words[x].split("")[0].ord == y)
    puts words[x]
  end
  y = y + 1
  x = x + 1
end
```

Comment: try `puts "Enter words separated by a space"; words = gets.split; p words.sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `while` loop terminates once it gets to an empty string (but still appends this to the list), meaning that the last element of `words` is an empty string. When you split the empty string on itself, you get an empty array.

```
"".split("") #=> []
"".split("")[0] #=> nil
```

You are eventually hitting this point in your second loop, and calling `.ord` on `nil`. You could avoid this by not including the empty string as part of the `words` array.

Comment: Hello. And thank a lot. It's no longer showing the message. I'm also changing the code in accordance with what you've said. I've realised it would be better to use variable "x".length - 1 as a loop, with the y loop within that.

Still not working, but I'm past that hurdle. Thank you very much, I would not have been able to solve that problem.

Comment: @ChrisK I'm glad it helped. Are you able to accept the answer?

Comment: Hi. I know this is late. But how do I accept the answer?